# Why does MySQL Workbench hang forever on queries that run instantly via command line?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This query (and others like it) fail to run on MySQL Workbench but returns results nearly instantly when I use SSH to log into the server and then log into MySQL and paste the query in the terminal there.

What can I change about MySQL Workbench (or my queries or my tables) so that queries like this complete quickly instead of hang indefinitely?

I doubt I need to index my tables more (or differently) given that running the same query via command line works well.

Currently this one returns ~12k rows.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(x.fullNameFilled, ' ', 1) AS 'first_name',
    IF(INSTR(x.fullNameFilled, ' ') = 0,
        NULL,
        SUBSTRING(x.fullNameFilled FROM INSTR(x.fullNameFilled, ' ') + 1)) AS 'last_name',
        x.* FROM (
SELECT 
    IF ((c2.fullName IS NULL OR c2.fullName=""), c2.emailAddress, c2.fullName) AS fullNameFilled,
    c2.*,
      `cf2`.`visitedCalendar`,
    `cf2`.`requestedCall`,
    `cf2`.`clarityCallTimeUtc`,
    `cf2`.`clarityCallTimeLocal`,
    `cf2`.`visitedApp`,
    `cf2`.`applied`,
    `cf2`.`receivedOffer`,
    gc.tag_labels
FROM
    contacts c2
        LEFT JOIN
    call_flows cf2 ON cf2.contact_id = c2.id
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        contact_tags.contact_id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(tags.label
                SEPARATOR ', ') AS tag_labels
    FROM
        tags
    LEFT JOIN contact_tags ON tags.id = contact_tags.tag_id
    GROUP BY contact_id) gc ON gc.contact_id = c2.id
WHERE
    c2.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            c.id
        FROM
            tags t
                LEFT JOIN
            contact_tags ct ON ct.tag_id = t.id
                LEFT JOIN
            contacts c ON c.id = ct.contact_id
        WHERE
            (t.label LIKE 'unsub%')
                OR (t.slug IN (
                'deposit_paid',
                'current_client',            
                'app_declined')))
        AND id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            c.id
        FROM
            contacts c
                LEFT JOIN
            call_flows cf ON cf.contact_id = c.id
                LEFT JOIN
            webcasts w ON w.contact_id = c.id
        WHERE
            (c.revenueCollectedAlready >= 7)
                OR (cf.appRating <= 1)
                OR (cf.attendance = 'flaked')
                OR (cf.receivedOffer <> 'No offer yet')
                OR (w.momentOfOfferUtc IS NOT NULL))

) x
 LIMIT 20000;
```

Comment: Side note: In MySQL Workbench you can use Ctrl + Alt + Enter to view as vertical text output which is similar to viewing on terminal.

Comment: `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is terribly inefficient.  See if you can reformulate the query to avoid those.  It might help to post `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @RickJames It’s weird that it works instantly via terminal though.